# C++ function in python from .dll using ctypes - function not found and access violation

Tags: python, c++, dll, g++, ctypes

I have this simple C++ code named `hello.cpp` which has a function to print "Hello world"

```
#include <iostream>

void hello_world();

int main() {
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
}

void hello_world() {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

I build the .dll (~1.9mb) using:

```
g++ -c hello.cpp
g++ -static -fPIC -o hello.dll hello.o
```

(using `-shared` gives a `WinError 126 ... module not found` when trying to access it in python)

The python code is:

```
from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('hello.dll')
lib.hello_world()
```

This throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: function 'hello_world' not found
```

I've read people mention that a `__declspec(dllexport)` wrapper is necessary and so is a `extern "C"` so that the code doesn't get "mangled". So now using that as the code:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void hello_world();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Opened" << std::endl;
}


void hello_world() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

The python line `lib.hello_world()` now raises:

```
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x000E28A0
```

What are the issues here? How can I get python to recognise and run the C++ function in the .dll? Can I skip the middleman and somehow run a C++ function from a .cpp file or a .o file?

edit:

Using eryksun's answer, it turns out that the dllexport isn't needed. The extern "C" is a must though

Comment: __1__: You are mixing c compilers and _C_ (_C++_) runtimes (_Python_ is compiled with _VStudio_ while your _.dll_ with _g++_). __2__: Your _.dll_ has a `main` function which qualifies it as an executable (not to mention the lack of `-shared` linker flag).

Comment: @CristiFati Changing the name of the function in my C++ code from main to anything else gives me a `undefined reference to \`WinMain@16'` error when on the 2nd step of the g++ process. Could you elaborate on the "Python is compiled with VStudio"?

Comment: That's usually because you're building a _Windows Application_ (check [\[MSDN\]: /SUBSYSTEM (Specify Subsystem)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) linker flag).

Comment: Should I be building a Windows application or not in this case? I didn't know .o or .dlls were considered applications. If yes or even if not, what should I do instead with g++?

Comment: I see that _g++_ is calls (or mimics) _VStudio_ _C++_ compiler. How did you get _g++_? Are you using _Cygwin_? Regarding your question, it shouldn't matter as long as it's a _.dll_. For _gcc_ (I think _g++_ as well) `-shared` builds a shared object. For _VStudio_ linker it's `/DLL` flag that does the same thing.

Comment: g++ is from MinGW's /bin/ folder in my PATH. I changed "main()" to "hello()", ran it with shared, and ran it again in Python. It's giving me the same error I talked about in the post: `OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`

Comment: You should probably add a [\[MSDN\]: DllMain entry point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx)  (and simply `return TRUE;`) as I don't know if _MinGW_ adds it by default.

Comment: The DLL that isn't found is probably the C++ standard library. Try adding the option `-static-libstdc++`.

Comment: @eryksun Unfortunately, no change with `g++ -shared -static-libstdc++ -o hello.dll hello.o`

Comment: @CristiFati Tried inserting an empty return true "DLLMain" block but it had no effect

Comment: Check the dependencies using `objdump -p hello.dll | grep "DLL Name"`.

Comment: @eryksun Dependencies are `KERNEL32.dll`, `msvcrt.dll`, `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` and `libstdc++-6.dll`

Comment: Try `-static -shared` -- as weird as that sounds.

Comment: @eryksun that worked! please put this as an answer so it's not buried in the comments. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @eryksun, this was solved in this case by compiling like this:

```
g++ -c hello.cpp
g++ -static -shared -o hello.dll hello.o
```

Having the C++ code set up like so:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Opened" << std::endl;
}

void hello_world() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}

extern "C" {
    void hello_world();
}
```

And running it from Python as usual:

```
from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('hello.dll')
lib.hello_world()
```

Comment: put extern "C" {
    void hello_world();
}

As top declaration, instead of last for it to work. At least for me that change things..